# Error while adding lightning component to lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I have created the custom lightning component named “TestComponentWithHTML”. But while adding this component to the lightning record page named “Test with HTML Tags”, I’m getting error and component is not added. I created the page using lightning app builder

[image]

The code in lightning component is:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
Hello World
<p>Hello in para</p>
<br/>
<lightning:formattedText value ="Hello World in lightning component"/>
```

Bundle version settings:

[image]

Can you guys help please?

Thanks

Comment: Share your code. Issue looks like with `lightningformattedText`

Comment: I have added the code @TusharSharma

Comment: No complex code. Just I'm starting out with the lightning

Comment: what is the API version you are using?

Comment: I have shared the Bundle version settings.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have posted has (the correct) `value` attribute name but the error message has (an incorrect) `values` attribute name. Use that correct `value` attribute name.